# cant install MVC4 Beta?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I can't seem to install MVC4 beta on my PC. The error message popups right after clicking on install package, and it says that MVC4 is not compatible with current version of .NET. I have't installed Visual studio developer release 11 or .NET 4.5.Anybody can help me out ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should download and install [ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta for Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=28942).

Answer (score 0):

If you open the logfile after the setup has failed, your logfile will probably end with the condition checking part like this:

[1940:240C][2012-02-27T12:00:58]: Condition 'netfx4 >= v4.0.30319' evaluates to true.

[1940:240C][2012-02-27T12:00:58]: Condition 'NOT (netfx4 = v4.5.40805)' evaluates to true.

Please check which condition evaluates to false. If it's the 'netfx4 >= v4.0.30319' than (re)install .Net 4.0.

In my case I had already installed .Net 4.5 and after removal I had to reinstall .Net 4.0 before I could install the MVC 4 BETA.

Comment: Both of those statements evaluate to true for me, and I'm having this same problem. Here's my install log: https://pastee.org/9usu3 Ideas?

Comment: Condition '(xcor2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (xcor2010_exists)' evaluates to false. That's the one that's causing the issue that it will not install. Do you have service pack 1 installed in visual studio 2010? You can check it in the about page of Visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is caused by antivirus software. I noticed the 0x80070005 message in the install log, which is "access denied". Since I was running the installer as administrator, it got me thinking antivirus was the culprit. I had my LAN administrator temporarily disable a McAfee access protection rule, and the install completed successfully.

I wish I would have thought to just look in the McAfee Access Protection Log, and I would have seen this:

```
2/24/2012 11:03:00 AM Blocked by Access Protection rule DOR\rb2007 C:\Users\rb2007\Downloads\AspNetMVC4Setup.exe \REGISTRY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce\{c6bc2507-baad-4168-a836-2d5faf5763cd} Common Maximum Protection:Prevent programs registering to autorun Action blocked : Create
```

After my LAN administer made the change, my Access Protection Log says this:

```
2/29/2012 3:45:09 PM Would be blocked by Access Protection rule  (rule is currently not enforced) DOR\Rb2007 C:\Users\rb2007\Downloads\AspNetMVC4Setup.exe \REGISTRY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce\{c6bc2507-baad-4168-a836-2d5faf5763cd} Common Maximum Protection:Prevent programs registering to autorun Action blocked : Create
```

That bit about .NET 4.5 is a pretty misleading error message from the installer.